# Hide the keyboard when enter button is pressed - Android WebView

Tags: android

When the keyboard opens, the <kbd>⏎</kbd> button doesn't do anything when pressed for my number type input field `<input name="age" id="age" type="number">` in my index.html page. Is it possible to close/hide this <kbd>⏎</kbd> button when pressed?

I have tried different answers but I couldn't make any of them work. Kindly suggest me what I'm doing wrong.

This is my main activity. I'm using [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) as WebView component.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
            .init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setListener(this, this);

        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();
                int type = hr.getType();

                if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my manifest xml:

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you in hiding the keyboard when the ENTER button is pressed after after entering some details.

```
textInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textInput);

// kill keyboard when enter is pressed
textInput.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
     /**
      * This listens for the user to press the enter button on 
      * the keyboard and then hides the virtual keyboard
      */
    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ( (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) &&
             (arg1           == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)   )
        {               
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textInput.getWindowToken(), 0);   
                return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
} );
```

But if you want to use a single line instead of multiple lines in edit text then simply add `android:maxLines="1"` under the EditText in the layout file to hide the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any suggestion how should I use it in my Main activity?